# Get a specific formatted string from a string in C# or SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, format

I have file names like: `abc 99 rep_DD_MM_YYYY_file_v-X.XX.zip` where `DD_MM_YYYY` is date and `X.XX` is the version. (eg. `abc 99 rep_01_01_2012_file_v-1.00`).

I need to compare in C# or SQL Server the two strings:

- `abc 99 rep_DD_MM_YYYY_file_v-X.XX.zip`
- `abc 99 rep_01_01_2012_file_v-1.00`

get extract of the values of the position `DD`, `MM`, `YYYY` & `XXX` of the 2nd string and then arrange them into `YYYYMMDDXXX` format to compare which one is the latest one.

Please can any one suggest me how can I do this comparison in C# or T-SQL ?

Comment: does it's always contains "abc 00 rep" and "file"?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to parse the DateTime from both strings with [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It could be done with regex. Since I really suck with regex, I will propose another way:

```
var day = fileName.SubString(11,2);
var month = fileName.SubString(14,2);
var year = fileName.SubString(17,4);
var version = fileName.SubString(29,4);

var result = String.Concat(year,month,day,version);
```

Comment: It's possible that some of the string indexes were wrong. I suppose you get the idea of the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @filename varchar(50)
set @filename = 'abc 99 rep_01_01_2012_file_v-1.00'

declare @date varchar(10)
select @date = substring(@filename, 12, 10)
select @date

declare @xxx varchar(10)
select @xxx = replace(right(@filename,4),'.','')
select @xxx


select right(@date,4) + right(left(@date,5),2) + left(@date,2) + @xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

The position of "**DD**", "**YYYY / YY**", "**MM / MMM**" may vary. So I need more complex date parser.

The parser I'm using now:

```
public void Main()
    {
        string name = "bmsa1110_v1.1.zip";
        string varPattern = "####YYMM##XXX####";

        getVarPart(name, varPattern);
    }

private string getVarPart(string name, string varPattern)
    {
        StringBuilder name_sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(name);
        StringBuilder varPattern_sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(varPattern);

        string YEAR = null;
        string MONTH = null;
        string DAY = null;
        string VERSION = null;

        for (int j = 0; j < varPattern_sb.Length; j++)
        {
            switch (varPattern_sb[j])
            {
                case 'Y':
                    YEAR = YEAR + name_sb[j];
                    name_sb[j] = '#';
                    break;
                case 'M':
                    MONTH = MONTH + name_sb[j];
                    name_sb[j] = '#';
                    break;
                case 'D':
                    DAY = DAY + name_sb[j];
                    name_sb[j] = '#';
                    break;
                case 'X':
                    VERSION = VERSION + name_sb[j];
                    name_sb[j] = '#';
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        string varPart = YEAR + MONTH + DAY + VERSION;
        return varPart;
    }
```

Though, Thanks all for your answer. If you have any suggestion, please share..